# Preview actual image of PathGeometry in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm-light, preview, pathgeometry

In my application there is a common Icon.xaml file which contains many PathGeometry Figures having unique key names like as shown below.

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="CloseGeometry" Figures="m 357.0883 499.0572 12.62375 12.6275 5.31375 -5.31625 -12.62625 -12.62625 12.62625 -12.61875 -5.31375 -5.3125 -12.62375 12.62 -12.6325 -12.62 -5.30375 5.3125 12.6175 12.61875 -12.6175 12.62625 5.30375 5.31625 12.6325 -12.6275 z"/>
<PathGeometry x:Key="NormalGeometry" Figures="M4.3685131,23.127279L4.3685131,47.283243 47.117023,47.283243 47.117023,23.127279z M25.087107,13.948568C23.539013,13.948568 22.286318,15.201555 22.286318,16.74834 22.286318,18.292325 23.539013,19.547214 25.087107,19.547214 26.6327,19.547214 27.886597,18.292325 27.886597,16.74834 27.886597,15.201555 26.6327,13.948568 25.087107,13.948568z M16.126242,13.948568C14.580646,13.948568 13.326751,15.201555 13.326751,16.74834 13.326751,18.292325 14.580646,19.547214 16.126242,19.547214 17.673136,19.547214 18.928329,18.292325 18.928329,16.74834 18.928329,15.201555 17.673136,13.948568 16.126242,13.948568z M7.1679735,13.948568C5.621069,13.948568 4.3685136,15.201555 4.3685131,16.74834 4.3685136,18.292325 5.621069,19.547214 7.1679735,19.547214 8.713438,19.547214 9.9674625,18.292325 9.9674625,16.74834 9.9674625,15.201555 8.713438,13.948568 7.1679735,13.948568z M0,10.684L53.755001,10.684 53.755001,51.668001 0,51.668001z M8.5679998,0L58.668022,0 64,0 64,5.6864691 64,45.317999 58.668022,45.317999 58.668022,5.6864691 8.5679998,5.6864691z"/>
<PathGeometry x:Key="MaximiseGeometry" Figures="M5.2010002,14.812L5.2010002,43.573997 56.098,43.573997 56.098,14.812z M29.868601,3.8869994C28.026201,3.8869996 26.534,5.3791947 26.534,7.2190399 26.534,9.0588851 28.026201,10.553 29.868601,10.553 31.7085,10.553 33.202,9.0588851 33.202,7.2190399 33.202,5.3791947 31.7085,3.8869996 29.868601,3.8869994z M19.200649,3.8869994C17.359457,3.8869996 15.867001,5.3791947 15.867001,7.2190399 15.867001,9.0588851 17.359457,10.553 19.200649,10.553 21.042044,10.553 22.536999,9.0588851 22.536999,7.2190399 22.536999,5.3791947 21.042044,3.8869996 19.200649,3.8869994z M8.5339746,3.8869994C6.6931,3.8869996 5.2010002,5.3791947 5.2010002,7.2190399 5.2010002,9.0588851 6.6931,10.553 8.5339746,10.553 10.37495,10.553 11.867,9.0588851 11.867,7.2190399 11.867,5.3791947 10.37495,3.8869996 8.5339746,3.8869994z M0,0L63.999001,0 63.999001,48.792999 0,48.792999z"/>
<PathGeometry x:Key="MinimiseGeometry" Figures="M 0 1, 1 1 "/>
```

.....

But my problem is that there are around 300 to 400 different PathGeometries and it becomes difficult to check whether particular type of Image exists or not.

Example:

If new WPF form is gettign developed by programmer in which s\he needs to use delete Icon then s\he will first check in Icon.xaml file whether it already exists or not, if not then it will be added.But this checking needs to be done manually which is a pain.

So is there any simplest way to preview or check whether particular iamge exists or not.

Comment: If your `Icon.xaml` file is maintained in key alphabetical order, it makes it a little less tedious to search it manually.  If your developer does a `Search In Files` for the text `x:Key="Delete` ("Delete" is the example you used) this may be sufficiently fast for your needs, so long as icons are named the same by all developers.  But as far as viewing them? You will need to write a program that displays them for you.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I did sometime back..I wrote a separate application which will take xaml file as input and will display all the images with corresponding names below to it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I konw two tools can help you preview `PathGeometry` data of xaml.

1. **XamlPadX**

Download: [XamlPadX v4.0](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/08/96/78/18/XamlPadX.zip).

```xml
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
  <Grid>
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M4.3685131,23.127279L4.3685131,47.283243 47.117023,47.283243 47.117023,23.127279z M25.087107,13.948568C23.539013,13.948568 22.286318,15.201555 22.286318,16.74834 22.286318,18.292325 23.539013,19.547214 25.087107,19.547214 26.6327,19.547214 27.886597,18.292325 27.886597,16.74834 27.886597,15.201555 26.6327,13.948568 25.087107,13.948568z M16.126242,13.948568C14.580646,13.948568 13.326751,15.201555 13.326751,16.74834 13.326751,18.292325 14.580646,19.547214 16.126242,19.547214 17.673136,19.547214 18.928329,18.292325 18.928329,16.74834 18.928329,15.201555 17.673136,13.948568 16.126242,13.948568z M7.1679735,13.948568C5.621069,13.948568 4.3685136,15.201555 4.3685131,16.74834 4.3685136,18.292325 5.621069,19.547214 7.1679735,19.547214 8.713438,19.547214 9.9674625,18.292325 9.9674625,16.74834 9.9674625,15.201555 8.713438,13.948568 7.1679735,13.948568z M0,10.684L53.755001,10.684 53.755001,51.668001 0,51.668001z M8.5679998,0L58.668022,0 64,0 64,5.6864691 64,45.317999 58.668022,45.317999 58.668022,5.6864691 8.5679998,5.6864691z" />  
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Then put the PathGeometry data (string of the node "Figures") to the value of inside "Data":
[image]
Next, you need to click "Auto Parse" button in left top postion, you can view the rendering result (red border region in screenshot). See below, I just use the data second one from your data.

2. **WPF Geometry Transformation Tool**

Download: [WPF Geometry Transformation Tool](https://www.wpftutorial.net/downloads/GeometryTransformer.zip).
[image]
Put the string of the node "Figures" into the textarea of `Input Geometry`, then you can see the result (red border region in screenshot).